# Upload Photo to Instagram with InstaSharper in Asp.net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, instasharp

First I login by InstaSharper. I try to upload photo with caption by this code.

```
    var mediaImage = new InstaImage
    {
        Height = 1080,
        Width = 1080,
        URI = new Uri(
            Path.GetFullPath("image.jpg"), UriKind.Absolute).LocalPath
    };
    var r = await api.UploadPhotoAsync(mediaImage, "caption");
```

the image successfully upload without caption. why?

The r.Info result is "OK: No errors detected.";

Answer (score 0):

Check this library [InstagramApiSharp](https://github.com/ramtinak/InstagramApiSharp).

it's based on InstaSharper with more functions and bugfixes.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While links are great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)